# Calling a new Form from a separate thread and avoid frozing the form

Tags: c#

I am currently creating a chat system. The receiving end of the client side is managed by a separate thread so that when it receives a message from another client, a new Form is loaded bearing the message of the sender. The problem is, the newly loaded form is frozen and is not responding [due to the blocked methods I use (?)]. How can I solve that problem? I am new to C# so please put in the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is frozen because you created it on another thread and that thread didn't call Application.Run().  Which is required to 'pump the message loop'.  [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793283/two-ui-thread-in-c-windows-application/4793854#4793854).

Don't create windows on another thread.  Use BackgroundWorker or Control.BeginInvoke or Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to let the UI thread of your program create the window.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this background worker example with code which worked great for me.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)